# Issue with Django migrations when deploying in Prod via AWS Beanstalk

Tags: django, django-models, migration, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am struggling with Django migrations when deploying into several environments. I have the following ones:

- Dev locally on my laptop with sqlite3 database
- Test in AWS (deployed via Beanstalk) connected to AWS RDS Production Database
- Prod in AWS (deployed via Beanstalk) connected to AWS RDS Production Database.

My workflow is once I have done my dev locally, I deploy to the Test instance, which should make the backward compatible changes to the prod database, where I run my tests, before deploying to the Prod instance.

In my .gitignore, I have excluded all the migrations folder as when I used to apply the same migrations I created in dev, it lead to some inconsistencies and errors during deployment. I thought it would be cleaner to recreate the migrations on the test or prod servers when deploying.

In my .ebextensions I then have the following config that are executed when deploying the application:

`01_makemigration:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py makemigrations --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true`

However when I deploy to the Test platform after having made changes to my models, the migrations don't seem to happen. I have tried to run those commands manually but it tells me that everything is up to date and no migrations are to be applied.

I have also tried to "rebase" the migrations using the following sequence:

On the Database:

`> delete from django_migrations;`

On the App:

`> rm -rf calc/migrations/`

`> source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate`

`> python manage.py migrate --fake`

`> python manage.py makemigrations calc`

`> python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`

But it does not seem to work either.

Would someone be able to advise what is the right way of applying migrations in that type of scenario? I would prefer to avoid committing dev migrations and create new and clean ones on the test environment (and the prod database) but I dont seem to find the right way to do it.

Thank you
Regards
Yann

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must not exclude your migrations from git. They are a part of your code base and need to be deployed with your app. You shouldn't be running makemigrations in prod, only migrate.

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. Is there anyone else who have a different opinion (or agree with Daniel)? Doing some research I have seen both opinions so just want to double check if there are other options I could also explore

Comment: So Daniel,where should the makemigrations command be executed in prod?

Comment: Do note that you might have to use --fake-initial in your migrate like I did or you will have errors regarding some tables existing already.